# get view method is called equal to list items present on the screen of device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I am trying to implement custom listview , but there is problem that getview method is called equal to listitems Present on the screen of device, and when i scroll the list , then for remaining items the gitview method is called, and changes of previous list items is discarded..I want getview method is called for all items present in the list view at the start.

please help me...

Comment: this default behavior you can't change it....

Comment: @sanket : then what should i do, is there any other solution..

Comment: exaclty what you want you need? describe more

Comment: @sanket:in my listview each view contains one imageView and one Framelayout and framelayout contains button and linearlayout, and button is visible only when we swipe the linearlayout from right to left and button is invisible when we swipe the linearlayout from left to right. but when i swipe the 1 layout then 1-8-15...layouts get swipe because my screen contains 8 list items , then what should i do.. please help me..

Answer (score 0):

try this in getview mathod

```
RelativeLayout yourlayout= (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.content);

yourlayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
            {
                boolean isOnClick=true;

                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) 
                {

                    if(arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                    {
                        isOnClick = false;
                    }
                    else if(arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    {
                        if(!isOnClick)
                        {
                            x_up = (int) arg1.getX();
                            y_up = (int) arg1.getY();

                            Log.v("log","x up : "+x_up +" and y :"+y_up);
                            // showToast("x  up : "+x_up +" and y :"+y_up);
                            Log.v("log","difference is "+ (x_up-x_down));
                            if(x_up-x_down>50)
                            {
                                delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
                            else if(x_down-x_up>50)
                            {
                                delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

                            isOnClick = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            isOnClick = true;
                            Log.v("log", "clicekd");
                            if(delete.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                            {
                                delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            Intent i = new Intent(MyaLikeActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("userid", listitem.getUserId());
                            startActivity(i);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else if(arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    {
                        x_down = (int) arg1.getX();
                        y_down = (int) arg1.getY();

                        Log.v("log","x down : "+x_down +" and y :"+y_down);
                    }



                    return true;
                }
            });
```

by using this... delete button visible when you swipe left to right or right to left.... if delete button is visible than you can set your oncliclick listner..

Comment: i am not getting the code properly , can you tell mi something about code , which you have given to me...please.